# Hisoka role in Hunter X Hunter

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

What is Hisoka's character in Hunter x Hunter?

I cannot describe his character from Hunter X Hunter.

Comment: "bad guy or good guy" is totally relative to your opinion (or how you see things), anyway, in my perspective, he has an extreme last for power, that's all.

Comment: I can't post the link right now, but you would benefit from reading up on orange blue morality (yeah TVTropes is probably best).  Most characters exhibit this to some degree in Hunter x Hunter.  While some moralities here are shades of grey, most don't fit properly with common good/neutral/evil alignments.

Answer (score 5):

By our real-world definition of evil, yeah, he is. But Hunter X Hunter morality is pretty grey, so in-universe he's not really "evil" per say.

I wouldn't say he's an anti-hero or even evil, though. He is selfish, a hedonist. He took the hunter exam for his own benefit and entertainment; he spared Gon, multiple times, so he that could grow into a stronger opponent(can be compared to a farmer feeding his cattle); he helped Kurapika so that he could fight Chrollo, and he fought alongside Illumi to protect Gon and/or fight strong opponents along the way. He has also killed a lot of people who weren't challenging enough for him throughout the series.

He is a bloodthirsty hedonist who lives almost entirely in the moment and is always looking for stronger opponents to challenge himself. He is selfish, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

In a Dungeons and Dragons alignment matrix, Hisoka might be best defined as "chaotic evil". Gary's characterization of Hisoka as a bloodthirsty hedonist fits well as a description of this alignment.  (Note that one can be evil without being bloodthirsty; but Hisoka is certainly that.)

The **chaotic** part of his nature is shown in the way he does what he wants when he wants.  He feels no need for subtlety or lies. In his mind, the world must adapt to him, not he to it. He will conform to rules when they serve his purpose.  Otherwise, rules are made to be broken. He has a sense of honor, which is seen in how he joined Gon's team and assisted them in the dodge ball game on Greed Island. He could have betrayed the team at any point, or get tired of it and not care any more. That would have been dishonorable, however.  Plus, he was having fun.

His **evil** is shown in the manner in which he defeats enemies.  He doesn't incapacitate temporarily, but humiliates them, usually resulting in painful death. He is driven to break them to a point of hopelessness, to see the look of defeat in their eyes, before finally disposing of them.  At the same time, he desires a challenge, which is why he allows Gon and company to continue to train and improve.  They are "unripe fruit", and will not be devoured until succulent.